# Save Link field in custom form

Tags: forms, blocks

I'm brand new at making custom forms and I'm having trouble getting the link field to save to the database.

The text body field saves fine but the link field object defined below it does not. I'm sure that this is an easy fix but I haven't been able to find proper documentation on adding the link field to custom forms.

Thanks in advance.

```
    /**
* Implements hook_block_configure().
*/

function My_Module_block_configure($delta='') {
$form = array();

switch($delta) {
case 'my_module' :
    // Text field form element
    $form['text_body'] = array(
        '#type' => 'text_format',
        '#title' => t('Enter your text here in WYSIWYG format'),
        '#default_value' => variable_get('text_variable', ''),
     );

     //link field
    $form['link'] = array(
        '#type' => 'link_field',
        '#size' => 20,
        '#field_name' => 'link',
    );      

    break;
}
return $form;
}

/**
* Implements hook_block_save().
*/
function My_Module_block_save($delta = '', $edit = array()) {
    switch($delta) {
    case 'my_module' :
        // Saving the WYSIWYG text
        variable_set('text_variable', $edit['text_body']['value']);
        variable_set('link_variable', $edit['link']['value']);

        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I get success with this. It needs to be improved though, especially the '#language' bit. What I found to be important was to wrap the link field in a container and set '#tree' to true to group it under its key. And the link field is a multi-value field with a link title and url, so you have to take care of that.

```
function MYMODULE_block_configure($delta='') {
  $form = array();

  switch($delta) {
    case 'my_module' :
      // Text field form element
      $form['text_body'] = array(
        '#type' => 'text_format',
        '#title' => t('Enter your text here in WYSIWYG format'),
        '#default_value' => variable_get('text_variable', ''),
      );

      //link field
      $form['link_container'] = array(
        '#type' => 'container',
        '#attributes' => array('class' => array('some-class')),
        '#tree' => TRUE,
      );
      $form['link_container']['link'] = array(
        '#type' => 'link_field',
        '#field_name' => 'link_field',
        '#language' => 'und', // how to fix this??
        '#field_parents' => array(),
        '#delta' => 0,
        '#default_value' => array(
          'title' => variable_get('link_title', ''),
          'url' => variable_get('link_url', ''),
        ),
      );
      break;
  }
  return $form;
}

/**
 * Implements hook_block_save().
 */
function MYMODULE_block_save($delta = '', $edit = array()) {
  switch($delta) {
    case 'my_module' :
      // Saving the WYSIWYG text
      variable_set('text_variable', $edit['text_body']['value']);
      variable_set('link_title', $edit['link_container']['link']['title']);
      variable_set('link_url', $edit['link_container']['link']['url']);
      break;
  }
}
```

Comment: Success! I have also wondered about the language issue. When working with fields I have utilized the Entity API to take care of it however Im not to sure to to handle it here while defining forms either.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add format in your custom form field as  'format' => 'filter_html' or full_html
So form look like this way

```
$form['text_body'] = array(
        '#type' => 'text_format',
        '#title' => t('Enter your text here in WYSIWYG format'),
        '#default_value' => variable_get('text_variable', ''),
        'format' => 'filter_html'
     );
```

Also please check `<a>` tags are allowed in text format or not on path `'admin/config/content/wysiwyg/profile/filtered_html/edit'` and `'admin/config/content/formats/filtered_html'`

Hope it will help

Comment: Hi, I was actually asking about the link field that is defined below the text body. I just left the text_body in the code to show that its working as intended. Do you have any advice for the link form object?

Comment: Just output its value in submit function and pass string to variable_set() rather than passing object. I think it should work.